# 3-way Merge Sort C program

Tags: c, sorting, mergesort

I have trying to "upgrade" my normal merge sort for a school project. But my new code seems to not cooperate as it should

So I have a `MergeSort3way` function that splits the array inputed in 3 subarrays then it calls itself till the sort is finished but the outputs are far from correct.

```
void Mergesort3way(int A[], int n) {
    //Sort array A with division of 3
    int B[n / 3];
    int C[n / 3];
    int D[n / 3];
    int i, c;
    
    if (n > 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < n / 3; i++) {
            B[i] = A[i];
        }
        for (i = n / 3; i < 2 * n / 3; i++) {
            c = i - n / 3;
            C[c] = A[i];
        }
        for (i = 2 * n / 3; i < n; i++) {
            c = i - (2 * n / 3);
            D[c] = A[i];
        }
    
        Mergesort3way(B, n / 3);
        Mergesort3way(C, n / 3);
        Mergesort3way(D, n / 3);
        int bn = sizeof(B) / sizeof(B[0]);
        int cn = sizeof(C) / sizeof(C[0]);
        int dn = sizeof(D) / sizeof(D[0]);
        Merge3way(B, C, D, A, bn, cn, dn);  
    }
}
```

After that the `Merge3way` combines them into 1 single sorted array:

```
void Merge3way(int B[], int C[], int D[], int A[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, u = 0, k = 0;
    
    while (i < p && j < q && u < r) {
        if (B[i] < C[j]) {
            if (B[i] < D[u]) {
                A[k] = D[u];
                u++;
            } else {
                A[k] = B[i];
                i++;
            }
        } else {
            if (C[j] < D[u]) {
              A[k] = D[u];
              u++;  
            } else {
              A[k] = C[j];
              j++;
            }
        }
        k++;
    }
    int all = p + q + r;    
    if (i == p) {
        if (u == r) {
            while (j < q && k < all) {
                A[k] = C[j];
                k++;
                j++;            
            } 
        } else {
            while (u < r && k < all) {
                A[k] = D[u];
                k++;
                u++;
            }
        }
    } else if (j == q) {
        if (u == r) {
            while (i < p && k < all) {
                A[k] = B[i];
                k++;
                i++;            
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Can you suggest me any solution so I can sort as it should? I have been trying over 2 hours of modifying it and the result are always the same. Thanks in advance please no hard feeling as it is my first time using the site.

Comment: Don't arrays `C`and `D` hold, not `n/3` elements, but `2*n/3 - n/3` and `n - 2*n/3` elements, respectively? Aside: `2*n/3` is not always equal to `2*(n/3)`.

Comment: ...and if `n` is not a multiple of `3` then the three arrays defined, each holding `n/3` elements, will not hold `n` elements in total between them.

Comment: I suggest a single infinite loop, e.g. `while (1) { }`. In the body of the loop, find the best of three, keeping in mind that one or two lists may be empty. Add the best item to the output, and increment the corresponding index. At the end of the loop, check if all three lists are empty, and if so, `break` the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I think this part of your code,

```
while(i<p && j<q && u<r){
    if(B[i]<C[j]){
        if(B[i]<D[u]){
            A[k]=D[u];
            u++;
        }else{
            A[k]=B[i];
            i++;
        }
    }else{
        if(C[j]<D[u]){
          A[k]=D[u];
          u++;  
        }else{
          A[k]=C[j];
          j++;
        }
    }
    k++;
 }
```

needs to change to this:

```
while(i<p && j<q && u<r){
    if(B[i]<C[j]){
        if(B[i]<D[u]){
            A[k]=B[i];
            i++;
        }else{
            A[k]=D[u];
            u++;
        }
    }else{
        if(C[j]<D[u]){
          A[k]=C[j];
          j++;  
        }else{
          A[k]=D[u];
          u++;
        }
    }
    k++;
 }
```

And this portion of your code:

```
if(i==p){
    if(u==r){
     while(j<q && k<all){
        A[k]=C[j];
        k++;
        j++;            
     } 
    }else{
        while(u<r && k<all){
        A[k]=D[u];
        k++;
        u++;
        }
    }
}else if(j==q){
    if(u==r){
     while(i<p && k<all){
        A[k]=B[i];
        k++;
```

needs to change to *something* like this:

```
if (i < p && j < q){
  # append the result of normal merge of remaining elements of B and C to A
} else if (j < q && u < r) {
  # append the result of normal merge of remaining elements of C and D to A
} else if (i < p && u < r) {
  # append the result of normal merge of remaining elements of B and D to A
} else {
      if (i == p && j == q && u < r){
         # append remaining elements of D to A
      } else if (i < p && j == q && u == r){
         # append remaining elements of B to A
      } else if (i == p && j < q && u == r){
         # append remaining elements of C to A
      }
}
```

Although, as you said that you had a `normal mergesort` which you are trying to modify, well, how about if after sorting every `1/3`rd portion of the array, like this:

```
Mergesort3way(B,n/3);
Mergesort3way(C,n/3);
Mergesort3way(D,n/3);
```

you combine any of the two sorted portions first using `normal mergesort`, and then combine the result of both of them with the third portion again using `normal mergesort`. For example: first merge `sorted B` with `sorted C` using `normal mergesort`, let's call their result `BmC`, then merge their result `BmC` with `sorted D` using `normal mergesort`, leading us to final merge result: `BmCmD`.

Answer (score 0):

If this is supposed to be an ascending sort, then if (B[i] < C[j]) && (B[i] < D[u]), the code should do A[k] = B[i]. During the 3 way merge, once the end of a run is reached, the code needd to switch to a 2 way merge, and once another end of a run is reached, the code needs to copy the rest of the remaining run.

Example of a top down 4 way merge sort that uses insertion for small runs. This is old code that uses pointers instead of indexing, and goto for multiple code paths that converge to single code paths. The code does a one time copy of the input array, then alternates the direction of merge for each level of recursion to avoid any further copies.

During a 4 way merge, there are 3 compares for each element moved, but the number of moves is half that of a 2 way merge, so the total number of operations is essentially the same, but 4 way merge is a bit more cache friendly and is faster on modern systems (ones with 16 registers of which 9 are used for pointers).

```
typedef unsigned long long uint64_t;

static void InsertionSort(uint64_t *a, size_t bb, size_t ee)
{
size_t i = bb+1;
size_t j;
size_t t;
    while(i < ee){
        t = a[i];
        j = i;
        while((j > bb) && a[j-1] > t){
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            j -= 1;}
    a[j] = t;
    i += 1;}
}

/* merge from a to b */
static void Merge(uint64_t *a, uint64_t *b,
                  size_t bb, size_t m1, size_t m2, size_t m3, size_t ee)
{
uint64_t *p0r = a+bb;   /* run 0 */
uint64_t *p0e = a+m1;
uint64_t *p1r = p0e;    /* run 1 */
uint64_t *p1e = a+m2;
uint64_t *p2r = p1e;    /* run 2 */
uint64_t *p2e = a+m3;
uint64_t *p3r = p2e;    /* run 3 */
uint64_t *p3e = a+ee;
uint64_t *pbx = b+bb;

    /* 4 way merge */
    while(1){
        if(*p0r <= *p1r){
            if(*p2r <= *p3r){
                if(*p0r <= *p2r){
mrg40:              *pbx++ = *p0r++;    /* run 0 smallest */
                    if(p0r < p0e)       /* if not end run continue */
                        continue;
                    goto mrg3123;       /* merge 1,2,3 */
                } else {
mrg42:              *pbx++ = *p2r++;    /* run 2 smallest */
                    if(p2r < p2e)       /* if not end run continue */
                        continue;
                    goto mrg3013;       /* merge 0,1,3 */
                }
            } else {
                if(*p0r <= *p3r){
                    goto mrg40;         /* run 0 smallext */
                } else {
mrg43:              *pbx++ = *p3r++;    /* run 3 smallest */
                    if(p3r < p3e)       /* if not end run continue */
                        continue;
                    goto mrg3012;       /* merge 0,1,2 */
                }
            }
        } else {
            if(*p2r <= *p3r){
                if(*p1r <= *p2r){
mrg41:              *pbx++ = *p1r++;    /* run 1 smallest */
                    if(p1r < p1e)       /* if not end run continue */
                        continue;
                    goto mrg3023;       /* merge 0,2,3 */
                } else {
                    goto mrg42;         /* run 2 smallest */
                }
            } else {
                if(*p1r <= *p3r){
                    goto mrg41;         /* run 1 smallest */
                } else {
                    goto mrg43;         /* run 3 smallest */
                }
            }
        }
    }
    /* 3 way merge */
mrg3123: p0r = p1r;
         p0e = p1e;
mrg3023: p1r = p2r;
         p1e = p2e;
mrg3013: p2r = p3r;
         p2e = p3e;
mrg3012: while(1){
        if(*p0r <= *p1r){
            if(*p0r <= *p2r){
                *pbx++ = *p0r++;        /* run 0 smallest */
                if(p0r < p0e)           /* if not end run continue */
                    continue;
                goto mrg212;            /* merge 1,2 */
            } else {
mrg32:          *pbx++ = *p2r++;        /* run 2 smallest */
                if(p2r < p2e)           /* if not end run continue */
                    continue;
                goto mrg201;            /* merge 0,1 */
            }
        } else {
            if(*p1r <= *p2r){
                *pbx++ = *p1r++;        /* run 1 smallest */
                if(p1r < p1e)           /* if not end run continue */
                    continue;
                goto mrg202;            /* merge 0,2 */
            } else {
                goto mrg32;             /* run 2 smallest */
            }
        }
    }
    /* 2 way merge */
mrg212: p0r = p1r;
        p0e = p1e;
mrg202: p1r = p2r;
        p1e = p2e;
mrg201: while(1){
        if(*p0r <= *p1r){
            *pbx++ = *p0r++;            /* run 0 smallest */
            if(p0r < p0e)               /* if not end run continue */
                continue;
            goto cpy11;
        } else {
            *pbx++ = *p1r++;            /* run 1 smallest */
            if(p1r < p1e)               /* if not end run continue */
                continue;
            goto cpy10;
        }
    }
cpy11: p0r = p1r;
       p0e = p1e;
    /* 1 way copy */
cpy10:
    while (1) {
        *pbx++ = *p0r++;                /* copy element */
        if (p0r < p0e)                  /* if not end of run continue */
            continue;
        break;
    }
}

static void MergeSortR(uint64_t *b, uint64_t *a, size_t bb, size_t ee)
{
size_t m1;
size_t m2;
size_t m3;
    if (ee - bb < 2)                    /* if <   2 elements, nothing to sort */
        return;
    if (ee - bb <= 16){                 /* if <= 16 elements, insertion sort */
        InsertionSort(a, bb, ee);
        return;
    }
    m1 = bb + (ee + 0 - bb) / 4;        /* split into 4 parts */
    m2 = m1 + (ee + 1 - bb) / 4;
    m3 = m2 + (ee + 2 - bb) / 4;
    MergeSortR(a, b, bb, m1);           /* sort a[] to b[] */
    MergeSortR(a, b, m1, m2);
    MergeSortR(a, b, m2, m3);
    MergeSortR(a, b, m3, ee);
    Merge(b, a, bb, m1, m2, m3, ee);    /* merge b[] to a[] */
}

static void MergeSort(uint64_t *a, size_t n)
{
uint64_t *b;
size_t i;
    if (n < 2)                          /* if < 2 elements, nothing to sort */
        return;
    b = (uint64_t *)malloc(n * sizeof(uint64_t));
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)             /* one time copy */
        b[i] = a[i];
    MergeSortR(b, a, 0, n);             /* sort b[] to a[] */
    free(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in the code:

- the way you split the array into 3 blocks is incorrect: if `n` is not a multiple of 3, the 3 subarrays will have a combined length smaller than `n` and the second or third initialization loops may write beyond the end of `C` or `D` because of rounding effects.
- in case `n < 3`, defining variable length arrays of length zero has undefined behavior even if you do not use them.
- in `Merge3way`, the 3-way merge loop is correct, but once one the subarrays has been fully copied, you must perform 2-way merge on the remaining 2 subarrays. You skip this phase completely and instead just copy one of the remaining subarrays.

Here is a modified version with along with testing code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void Merge3way(int B[], int C[], int D[], int A[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, u = 0, k = 0;

    while (i < p && j < q && u < r) {
        if (B[i] <= C[j]) {
            if (B[i] <= D[u]) {
                A[k++] = B[i++];
            } else {
                A[k++] = D[u++];
            }
        } else {
            if (C[j] <= D[u]) {
                A[k++] = C[j++];
            } else {
                A[k++] = D[u++];
            }
        }
    }
    if (i == p) {
        // 2-way merge C and D
        while (j < q && u < r) {
            if (C[j] <= D[u]) {
                A[k++] = C[j++];
            } else {
                A[k++] = D[u++];
            }
        }
    } else
    if (j == q) {
        // 2-way merge B and D
        while (i < p && u < r) {
            if (B[i] <= D[u]) {
                A[k++] = B[i++];
            } else {
                A[k++] = D[u++];
            }
        }
    } else {
        // 2-way merge B and C
        while (i < p && j < q) {
            if (B[i] <= C[j]) {
                A[k++] = B[i++];
            } else {
                A[k++] = C[j++];
            }
        }
    }
    // copy remaining subarray
    while (i < p) {
        A[k++] = B[i++];
    }
    while (j < q) {
        A[k++] = C[j++];
    }
    while (u < r) {
        A[k++] = D[u++];
    }
}

void Mergesort3way(int A[], int n) {
    if (n < 3) {
        // less than 3 elements: test and swap values if 2 are present
        if (n == 2) {
            if (A[0] > A[1]) {
                int temp = A[0];
                A[0] = A[1];
                A[1] = temp;
            }
        }
    } else {
        //Sort array A with division of 3
        // compute subarray lengths with a difference of at most 1
        int bn = (n + 2) / 3;
        int cn = (n - bn + 1) / 2;
        int dn = n - bn - cn;
        int B[bn];
        int C[cn];
        int D[dn];
        int j = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < bn; i++) {
            B[i] = A[j++];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < cn; i++) {
            C[i] = A[j++];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < dn; i++) {
            D[i] = A[j++];
        }
        Mergesort3way(B, bn);
        Mergesort3way(C, cn);
        Mergesort3way(D, dn);
        Merge3way(B, C, D, A, bn, cn, dn);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int array[1000];
    int n = sizeof(array) / sizeof(*array);
    srand(time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        array[i] = rand();
    }
    Mergesort3way(array, n);
    int bad = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
            printf("sort failed at %d: %d > %d\n", i, array[i - 1], array[i]);
            if (bad++ > 5)
                break;
        }
    }
    return !!bad;
}
```

`Merge3way()` can be further simplified using conditional operators and by combining boundary tests into the loop body. Using `a` as the index into `A` and `k` for the index into `D` is also more consistent:

```
void Merge3way(int B[], int C[], int D[], int A[], int p, int q, int r) {
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0, a = 0;

    while (i < p) {
        A[a++] = (j == q || B[i] <= C[j]) ?
            (k == r || B[i] <= D[k]) ? B[i++] : D[k++] :
            (k == r || C[j] <= D[k]) ? C[j++] : D[k++];
    }
    // 2-way merge C and D
    while (j < q) {
        A[a++] = (k == r || C[j] <= D[k]) ? C[j++] : D[k++];
    }
    // copy remaining subarray
    while (k < r) {
        A[a++] = D[k++];
    }
}
```